# kdb+/q indexing in functions

Tags: function, kdb

I am new to the kdb+/q language and am trying some basic online exercises.

I am trying to create a function that accepts a list and returns the list with the second item in the list doubled.

```
L:{[x;y] y:[1]; y*2; x}
```

My attempt consists of me assigning the function to `L`, outlining my parameters `x` and `y` and then my logic is assign the 2nd item in the list by indexing to the value `y` and multiply this value 2. I used `x` because I wanted to assign the list to `x` and then I output `x` at the end of the function. Each time I've tested it inputting a list `L 10 20 30 40 50` I have seen no change in the 2nd item. I need some help as to whether my syntax is incorrect or my logic is or both. I'm currently using [Q for Mortals](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/) as a reference. If it is my syntax that is wrong. What is the correct syntax for functions in q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are setting `y` to 1 and returning `x` unmodified.

The correct syntax for your method would be one of the following:

```
{[x]x[1]:2*x[1];x}
{[x]x[1]*:2;x}
```

In this case only one argument is needed. The first example instead of saving to a variable the second element is updated directly. The second example is more succinct but more or less the same expression.

An alternative and arguably cleaner way is:

```
{[x]@[x;1;2*]}
```

Which applies the function `2*` to the second element.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to do this. You only need one parameter in function to take the input list.

1. Update the value in the list and return the list.

   ```
   q) f:{x[1]*:2;x}
   q) f 1 2 3
   q) 1 4 3 // output
   ```

Function 'f' has a parameter 'x' which will be assigned to the input list.

2. Using [functional amend ('@')](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/amend/#functional-amend)

   ```
   q) f:{@[x;1;*;2]}
   q) f 1 2 3
   q) 1 4 3 //output
   ```